# Ошибка NullPointerException в коде kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

Ошибка:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: null cannot be cast to non-null type java.util.HashMap<kotlin.String, kotlin.Any?>{ kotlin.collections.TypeAliasesKt.HashMap<kotlin.String, kotlin.Any?> }

Код:

```
var users = (it.result.value as HashMap<String, Any?>).map {
            var user_list = it.value as HashMap<String, String>
            list_uid.add(it.key)
            return@map User(
                user_list.get("firstName"), user_list.get("lastName"),

                user_list.get("birthday"), user_list.get("country_live")
            )
        }
```

Comment: Видимо вот это `it.result.value` - `null`

Comment: как это можно решить? только проверкой?

Comment: можно написать `as?` тогда на выходе получите nullable-тип, если при касте что-то пойдет не так.

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map-not-null.html